# How to make desired Joomla site working on live server same as on Local Machine?

Tags: php, joomla, web-hosting

I have created a Joomla based website and willing to upload it on live server. I have never done the hosting before. please help me how shall i make this happen successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Database. You have to export your database from your local machine to the remote one (using phpMyAdmin for example)
2. Copy files. Copy your local files to the remote server. (using FTP for example)
3. Configuration files check. Some paths are hardcoded in it, and database credentials might be changed.

See also http://docs.joomla.org/Copying_a_Joomla_website

Answer (score 3):

There is a much easier way to do this. Look for a component called [Akeeba Backup](http://www.akeebabackup.com/). Install that on your local Joomla install. Then create a backup of your site.

Now using the backup from Akeeba your can restore your site onto any other server - live or test. The restore feature of Akeeba has a installer that is similar to the Joomla installer.

Very simple, very effective!